# Show Google Analytics 30 Day traffic on Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, google-analytics

I am building a custom WordPress Google Analytics plugin that will add a `/stats` page to every page on the site.  It will pull the data using the Google Analytics API and display several different stats.

One of those stats is the Page Visitors for the past 30 days and I would like to show it on a chart/graph using HighCharts.js

I took a demo and modified it the best I could to get it as close to what I need as I can but I need help now.

---

Here is the Data for the 30 days with the number of visitors on each day.  This JavaScript array is what will need to be used to populate the data on the graph...

My PHP code spits this out on the page where I need it in my JavaScript code...

```
[
    ["Dec 15", 1],
    ["Dec 16", 0],
    ["Dec 17", 0],
    ["Dec 18", 0],
    ["Dec 19", 0],
    ["Dec 20", 0],
    ["Dec 21", 0],
    ["Dec 22", 0],
    ["Dec 23", 0],
    ["Dec 24", 0],
    ["Dec 25", 1],
    ["Dec 26", 0],
    ["Dec 27", 0],
    ["Dec 28", 0],
    ["Dec 29", 2],
    ["Dec 30", 0],
    ["Dec 31", 0],
    ["Jan 1", 0],
    ["Jan 2", 0],
    ["Jan 3", 0],
    ["Jan 4", 0],
    ["Jan 5", 0],
    ["Jan 6", 0],
    ["Jan 7", 0],
    ["Jan 8", 0],
    ["Jan 9", 1],
    ["Jan 10", 0],
    ["Jan 11", 0],
    ["Jan 12", 1],
    ["Jan 13", 1],
]
```

---

My biggest problem with the demo code below is the x Axis along the bottom.  It need to be changed to show the days/date for the past 30 days.  The vertical Y Axis shows the number of visitors, that is set up already.

Below is the code I have from the demo so far....

JSFiddle Demo page - http://jsfiddle.net/g3550h7m/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: '30 Day Traffic Stats'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Page Traffic Stats'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + ' Visitors';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>on {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: '15',
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Page Visits',
            data: [
    ["Dec 15", 1],
    ["Dec 16", 0],
    ["Dec 17", 0],
    ["Dec 18", 0],
    ["Dec 19", 0],
    ["Dec 20", 0],
    ["Dec 21", 0],
    ["Dec 22", 0],
    ["Dec 23", 0],
    ["Dec 24", 0],
    ["Dec 25", 1],
    ["Dec 26", 0],
    ["Dec 27", 0],
    ["Dec 28", 0],
    ["Dec 29", 2],
    ["Dec 30", 0],
    ["Dec 31", 0],
    ["Jan 1", 0],
    ["Jan 2", 0],
    ["Jan 3", 0],
    ["Jan 4", 0],
    ["Jan 5", 0],
    ["Jan 6", 0],
    ["Jan 7", 0],
    ["Jan 8", 0],
    ["Jan 9", 1],
    ["Jan 10", 0],
    ["Jan 11", 0],
    ["Jan 12", 1],
    ["Jan 13", 1],
    ]
        }]
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data contains incorrect x values, it should be number or timestamp (for number xAxis type as you have), instead of strings. To convert dates to timestamp you can use Date.UTC() / Date.parse(). Second solution is set xAxis type as category.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish this goal however this code below does the desired output so I am going with it for now!  Might help someone else out as my searches found nothing like this online!

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#30daycontainer').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: '30 Day Traffic Stats'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },


        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Page Traffic Stats'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + ' Visitors';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                           stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#888888',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    radius: 4,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        },

        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Unique Visitors',
            data: <?php echo $chartData['uniquepageviews']; ?>,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $chartData['startdate']; ?>),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        },{
            name: 'Page Views',
            data: <?php echo $chartData['pageViews']; ?>,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $chartData['startdate']; ?>),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
            },

        ]

    });
});
</script>
```

There is lots of small changes but the biggest change is the `xAxis` to this...

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

Also in my `Series` I have added a `pointStart` and `pointInterval`

```
series: [{
    name: 'Unique Visitors',
    data: <?php echo $chartData['uniquepageviews']; ?>,
    pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $chartData['startdate']; ?>),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
},{
    name: 'Page Views',
    data: <?php echo $chartData['pageViews']; ?>,
    pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $chartData['startdate']; ?>),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    },
]
```

Comment: could you please send the full code including with the query?